# Using if statements with text strings in function - R

Tags: r

I am attempting to split my data into three separate dataframes (train, test, validate) using a function but it is not returning the results I require.

This is my function:

```
   splitData <- function(type) {
    set.seed(1337)
    rowTrain <- createDataPartition(y = cleaned.data$CHURN, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
    bufferDF <- cleaned.data[-rowTrain,]
    rowTest <- createDataPartition(y = cleaned.data$CHURN, p = 0.50, list = FALSE)
    if(type == "train") {cdTrain <- cleaned.data[rowTrain,]}
    if(type == "train") {cdTrain}
    if(type == "test") {cdTest <- cleaned.data[rowTest,]}
    if(type == "test") {cdTest}
    if(type == "validate") {cdValidate <- bufferDF[-rowTest,]}
    if(type == "validate") {cdValidate}
}
```

Could you please shine some light on where I am going wrong?

Cheers

Comment: why do you have two `if` statements for each type? Why not just do, e.g., `if(type=="train") {cdTrain<-cleaned.data[rowTrain,]; cdTrain}`?

Comment: @doviod great point... still reasonably new to R so learning bit by bit so cheers for that tip. I'm running the function using the command `cdTrain <- splitData(train)` to no avail. Also have tried `splitData("train")` and `splitData(type = "train")`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what results do you get from running it?

Comment: Check my reply to your comment down below @doviod :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `missing()` examines whether an argument was passed to the function it is within. Passing something like `train=="y"` is meaningless, because `train=="y"` is not an argument for the function splitData. If you're trying to make sure that the various variables were passed before you do something, it should be `if(!missing(train))`.

However, I'm not sure what your function hopes to achieve - it doesn't actually use any of the arguments it receives, other than to check if they exist or not...

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
splitData <- function(type) {
  set.seed(1337)
  rowTrain <- createDataPartition(y = cleaned.data$CHURN, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
  bufferDF <- cleaned.data[-rowTrain,]
  rowTest <- createDataPartition(y = cleaned.data$CHURN, p = 0.50, list = FALSE)
  if(type == "train") {cdTrain <- cleaned.data[rowTrain,]
    return(cdTrain)}
  if(type == "test") {cdTest <- cleaned.data[rowTest,]
    return(cdTest)}
  if(type == "validate") {cdValidate <- bufferDF[-rowTest,]
    return(cdValidate)}
}
```

Note that "validate" will give you a very short list, because you're using -rowTest created from the full data set on the shorted bufferDF, which only includes 30% of the data set. You might want to replace the line defining rowTest with something like:

```
rowTest <- createDataPartition(y = bufferDF, p = 0.50, list = FALSE)
```

Which will give you a sample of 50% of the test data.